# Good software for software planning?

Tags: c++, c

Is there software that can help create flow charts, class diagrams etc to help software development planning.

Thanks

Comment: Help with code construction or with project management?

Comment: Its in c++, but it can almost be language agnostic, just a way to create boxes that can have detailed description of the members and the whole class and a way to link them and add notes or something, a little but like Visio,

Comment: Ultimately, the best tool to help with software planning is usually a very large whiteboard.

Comment: @bta: Agreed, though sometimes it's nice to have a permanently stored product that isn't a photograph of a whiteboard, unless your handwriting is *really* good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create all kinds of charts and diagrams with something like Microsoft Visio or the open-source [Dia](http://projects.gnome.org/dia/).

If you want to auto-generate things like this, take a look at using a UML-based tool.  A list of some UML tools is available [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_UML_tools).

Answer (score 2):

As a open-source fan and contributor, I tried Dia on Ubuntu, but it was way too clumsy for what I needed to do. One thing I wanted to do was get raster or vector snapshots of fairly complex multi-page diagrams and put them in a wiki page, and Dia really couldn't cope with that - the fonts went all wonky and so on.

If you try Dia and find it doesn't work for you, and you have access to a Mac, try OmniGraffle. It's pretty slick.

Comment: I always found Dia too clumsy too, you spend more time drawing boxes and lines than you spend modelling your ideas.

Answer (score 2):

I use [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org) in conjunction with [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/). Search for both on Stack Overflow, there are lots of tips,such as [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51667/best-tips-for-documenting-code-using-doxygen/446598).

In particular, as a highly-iterative developer, I really like that the diagrams I create with Graphviz are stored in a simple textual fashion and so can be included in version control and diff nicely.

There's a very nice iPad/iPhone version of Graphviz called [Instaviz](http://instaviz.com/) which allows you to exchange diagrams with your desktop machine and tweak them on the pad.

Answer (score 0):

We used Rational Rose in class to do that. It also does much more:
http://www-01.ibm.com/software/awdtools/developer/rose/

Comment: <personal-opinion>I wouldn't recommend a Rational product even to my archenemy (if I had an archenemy, that is).   They are very clumsy and extraordinarily difficult to use.</personal-opinion>

Comment: Don't forget expensive enough to make an angel cry.  N times the price for 1/Nth the capability, like so many IBM products.

Answer (score 0):

I use this [Software Ideas Modeller](http://www.softwareideas.net/), or rather, used to before everything was built into Visual Studio (Ultimate with the many plugins that are available for it).