# Update doxygen doc for sub directories

Tags: doxygen

I am running doxygen for C/C++ documentation on a large codebase which has many different directories d1, d2 d3 etc. When I run my doxygen by giving the INPUT as top level directory, it generates document for all directories.

Now if only doc in one of sub directory has changed, how can I generate/update doc for only the modified directory. If I give INPUT as subdirectory d1, the generated index.html/main.html has doc specific to only that directory loosing other directories doc.

Is there a way to update the doc for only a particular directory ?

-Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I believe something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/569495/3804525) would be in order. I haven't tried myself but something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/445018/3804525) should help.

By dividing it up into parts and then instead running a script that checks diff as in the first link or by maybe looking at when file was changed. This script could then invoke the changed folder as target for doxygen to run on.